# How can I get one month of battery time for an IOT application?

Tags: custom-roms, battery-life

I like tinkering with Arduino and similar prototyping platforms for IOT applications. Often I want to read a sensor value and send it to some cloud service and repeat this, say, once every hour.

Today I realised that my old Android phone that currently lies unused in my underwear drawer has huge potential for being a powerful sensor platform.

Let's say I only want to run a single app on the phone that does the following:

```
1. Read sensor value (accelerometer/temperature/light/...)
2. Send value via http
3. Sleep for one hour
4. Goto 1
```

**Would it be possible to get one month of battery time on an Android phone running this program?**

My first test would probably be to enable flight mode and uninstall as many apps as possible. Is there a better way? Maybe there is a custom ROM or similar that is specially made for this?

Comment: Well, this might be of help:   https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Comment: Also seeing your requirements it looks like you will need to build a custom ROM yourself. But even then, one month might be unachievable.